# How do I iterate over a range in ERB?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to generate a dropdown with the alphabet in it. Weird, I know, I'm making an old school arcade style name selector for a game (3/4 letters) selectable with arrow keys.

So far I've got this:

```
<%= select_tag(:letters) do %>
    <% ('A'..'Z').each do |letter| %>
      <%= content_tag(:option, letter, value: letter) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the `<select>` tag, but the `option` tags are not generated. I'm sure it's just a small syntax error but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<%= select_tag(:letters, options_for_select(('A'..'Z').to_a)) %>
```